# LDAP Bad Search Filter

Tags: ldap

I'm using an open source software called LDAP Account Manager to manage ldap users, groups, and hosts for my company. I'm having a weird problem though, and I was hoping someone could give me an idea what's happening on the LDAP side of things as opposed to the actual software.

So here's the problem in a nutshell.

1. The software can find all users at the following suffix:

   ou=Users,ou=Accounts,dc=xxxx,dc=com
2. When I try to view the details of one of these users, I get an error that says:

   Bad search filter
3. Here's the weird part. When I add a new user, the entry appears with the other users at the same suffix.

   ou=Users,ou=Accounts,dc=xxxx,dc=com

In other words, all of the users (the old ones that were already in the LDAP tree, and the new one I added, exist in the same place).

1. I can navigate to the new user at:

   CN=User, Test,ou=Users,ou=Accounts,dc=xxxxx,dc=com

But I can't navigate to any of the existing users at this location (I get the Bad Search Filter error):

```
CN=Fakename, John,ou=Users,ou=Accounts,dc=xxxxx,dc=com
```

This seems inconsistent, and I'm trying to brainstorm what could be happening. The users exist in the same location, but I get an error when accessing some, but not others. Could this be a permissions issue, or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds very much like your software has troubles encoding the `,` (comma) separating the name and the surname in the create command or in the search filter.

Comment: If you can specify a full DN, try typing the naming element as cn=Fakename\, John (Escape the comma with a backslash).